# Declare array object inside the interface

Tags: java

I have scenario like this, is it a good implementation or not?

```
public interface Vehicle {
// is it possible to declare array in interface?

//so it is possible and no compilation errors

Vehicle[] vehicles1 = new Vehicle[10];


}
```

Comment: Defining storage types falls within implementation details, you should ***not*** be doing that in an interface, which is only concerned with declaring behavior (not defining it).

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to declare a field like that. It will be `public`, `static` and `final` (which basically makes it a constant) even if you don't explicitly state it.

Whether it is a good practice or not really depends on what you will be using it for. It is discouraged in most cases though.

Answer (score 0):

you it is possible, but the Attribute is public and this is not a good style. The Attribute should be private and accessed by `getter` and `setter` Methods.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only declare `public` methods and `static final` fields (constants) in interfaces.

Such a thing is possible, but not what you want:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public static final Vehicle[] vehicles1 = new Vehicle[10];
}
```

I suggest using the usual `get` and `set` patterns:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    void setVehicles1(Vehicle[] vehicles);
    Vehicle[] getVehicles1();
}
```

Comment: you can declare it like `Vehicle[] vehicles1 = new Vehicle[10];` - `public` `static` and `final` modifiers will be added implicitly

Comment: Wasn't sure about that (because the op suggested that he gets compile errors).